# SharePoint 2019 on Premise environment for development and testing

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I need to test PowerShell Script on the SharePoint 2019 On Premise environment.
Is there any test or development environment available to run the script.
I heard about CloudShare.

I search a lot for test environment but couldn't find it.